# Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“default-src”)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, nginx, content-security-policy

My angular.js app works fine on local machine, but when I deploy it on server using nginx, it gives me an error

```
    Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“default-src”). app:1
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“default-src”). Source: .vimvixen-console-frame {
  margin: 0;
 .... app:1
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“default-src”). app:1
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“default-src”). Source: .vimvixen-hint {
  background-color: yel.... app:1
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“default-src”). app:1
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“default-src”). Source: .vimvixen-console-frame {
  margin: 0;
 .... app:1
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“default-src”). app:1
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“default-src”). Source: .vimvixen-hint {
  background-color: yel.... app:1
```

And this is what I get on my browser

[image]
can anyone please help me in resolving this issue

Answer (score 1):

This issue was I had an vim vinex addon installed on on my firefox, when I disabled the addon. I am not getting the error anymore